# How to use PHPCBF to fix one issue at a time?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I've added a PHPCS configuration to get some standards into a legacy project.

I'm using a relaxed version of PSR-2 as an interim step. Now what I want to do, is slowly remove the exclusions, one by one, committing the changes into Git each step of the way.

How do I go about running PHPCBF for a given configuration?

Within my ruleset, I have:

```
<arg name="tab-width" value="4"/>
<rule ref="PSR2">
    <exclude name="PSR1.Files.SideEffects.FoundWithSymbols"/>

    <exclude name="Generic.Files.LineLength.TooLong"/>
    <exclude name="Generic.Formatting.DisallowMultipleStatements.SameLine"/>
    <exclude name="Generic.Functions.FunctionCallArgumentSpacing.NoSpaceAfterComma"/>
    <exclude name="Generic.Functions.FunctionCallArgumentSpacing.SpaceBeforeComma"/>
    <!--<exclude name="Generic.PHP.LowerCaseConstant.Found"/>-->
    <!--<exclude name="Generic.PHP.LowerCaseKeyword.Found"/>-->
    <exclude name="Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowTabIndent"/>
    <exclude name="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent"/>

    <exclude name="PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration.MissingNamespace"/>

    <exclude name="PSR2.Classes.ClassDeclaration.CloseBraceAfterBody"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Classes.ClassDeclaration.SpaceBeforeBrace"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Classes.ClassDeclaration.OpenBraceNotAlone"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Classes.PropertyDeclaration.Underscore"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.ControlStructures.ControlStructureSpacing.SpacingAfterOpenBrace"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.ControlStructures.ElseIfDeclaration.NotAllowed"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.ControlStructures.SwitchDeclaration.BreakIndent"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.ControlStructures.SwitchDeclaration.BreakNotNewLine"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.ControlStructures.SwitchDeclaration.SpaceBeforeColonCASE"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.ControlStructures.SwitchDeclaration.SpaceBeforeColonDEFAULT"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature.MultipleArguments"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature.CloseBracketLine"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature.ContentAfterOpenBracket"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature.Indent"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature.SpaceAfterOpenBracket"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature.SpaceBeforeCloseBrace"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature.SpaceBeforeCloseBracket"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Methods.MethodDeclaration.Underscore"/>

    <exclude name="Squiz.Classes.ValidClassName.NotCamelCaps"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.SpaceAfterCloseParenthesis"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.SpaceAfterKeyword"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.SpaceAfterCloseBrace"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.SpaceAfterBracket"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.NewlineAfterOpenBrace"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.ControlStructures.ForLoopDeclaration.NoSpaceAfterFirst"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.ControlStructures.ForLoopDeclaration.NoSpaceAfterSecond"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.ControlStructures.ForEachLoopDeclaration.SpaceAfterOpen"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.ControlStructures.ForEachLoopDeclaration.SpaceBeforeClose"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.Functions.FunctionDeclarationArgumentSpacing.SpaceBeforeEquals"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.Functions.FunctionDeclarationArgumentSpacing.SpaceAfterDefault"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.Functions.FunctionDeclarationArgumentSpacing.SpacingAfterOpenHint"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration.SpaceAfterFunction"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration.BraceOnSameLine"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration.ContentAfterBrace"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration.SpaceAfterBracket"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.Functions.FunctionDeclarationArgumentSpacing.SpacingAfterOpen"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.Functions.FunctionDeclarationArgumentSpacing.SpacingBeforeClose"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.Scope.MethodScope.Missing"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.WhiteSpace.ScopeClosingBrace.ContentBefore"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.WhiteSpace.ScopeClosingBrace.Indent"/>
    <exclude name="Squiz.WhiteSpace.SuperfluousWhitespace.EndLine"/>

    <exclude name="Generic.ControlStructures.InlineControlStructure.NotAllowed"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.ControlStructures.ControlStructureSpacing.SpaceBeforeCloseBrace"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.ControlStructures.SwitchDeclaration.TerminatingComment"/>
    <exclude name="PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration.MultipleClasses"/>
    <exclude name="PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName.NotCamelCaps"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Files.EndFileNewline.NoneFound"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.Files.EndFileNewline.TooMany"/>
</rule>
<rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowSpaceIndent"/>
```

So, what I am asking is how I run PHPCBF for, for example, 'Generic.PHP.LowerCaseConstant.Found'.

So far I have tried the following:

```
   ./www/vendor/bin/phpcbf www/application --sniffs=Generic.PHP.LowerCaseConstant.Found
   ./www/vendor/bin/phpcbf www/application --sniffs=Generic.Sniffs.PHP.LowerCaseConstant.Found
   ./www/vendor/bin/phpcbf www/application --sniffs=Generic.Sniffs.PHP.LowerCaseConstantSniff
   ./www/vendor/bin/phpcbf www/application --standard=Generic --sniffs=Generic.Sniffs.PHP.LowerCaseConstantSniff
   ./www/vendor/bin/phpcbf -w www/application --standard=Generic --sniffs=Generic.Sniffs.PHP.LowerCaseConstantSniff
   ./www/vendor/bin/phpcbf -w www/application --standard=generic --sniffs=Generic.Sniffs.PHP.LowerCaseConstantSniff
```

None of which are correct. They just produce PHPCBF's help text.

Answer (score 3):

You can only fix the errors from an entire sniff at once and not a specific error message. So you'd have to run:

```
./www/vendor/bin/phpcbf www/application --standard=Generic --sniffs=Generic.PHP.LowerCaseConstant
```

To fix all errors reported by the `Generic.PHP.LowerCaseConstant` sniff

Comment: How do you alter properties using this method? For example, I want to use PSR2.ControlStructures.ControlStructureSpacing with spacing values of 1 instead of 0. Easy to do inside ruleset.xml for detection with phpcs, but I can't figure it out for phpcbf. Thanks.

Comment: @Trip You tell PHPCBF to use the same ruleset as PHPCS. So assuming your have a ruleset with this PSR2 sniff referenced in it, and your custom spacing values, if you want to fix just PSR2.ControlStructures.ControlStructureSpacing, you would run: phpcs /path/to/code --standard=/path/to/your/ruleset.xml --sniffs=PSR2.ControlStructures.ControlStructureSpacing

Comment: Thanks @Greg! I got caught up in thinking of the standard var as 'PSR1', 'PSR2', 'Generic', etc. and overlooked that my ruleset qualified as valid input.

Comment: I've tried to run `phpcbf --standard=PSR2 --sniffs=PEAR.Functions.FunctionCallSignature path/to/file.php`, but got "ERROR: No sniffs were registered". If I change standard to PEAR, too much changes (sniffs) have applied.

Comment: @Aliance No sniffs were registered because the PSR2 standard does not use that sniff. You will need to use `--standard=PEAR`. I have just tested PHPCBF again and can confirm it will only fix the things that the `PEAR.Functions.FunctionCallSignature` finds when you use those arguments. Run the same command with `phpcs` to see the list of errors that will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I wanted to fix an individual error that phpcs was throwing (I was using the -s flag to show the sniff code)

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 291 | ERROR | [x] There must not be a space between the question mark and the type in nullable type declarations
     |       |     (PSR12.Functions.NullableTypeDeclaration.WhitespaceFound)
```

Don't use the exact code shown above but instead something like this

```
./vendor/bin/phpcbf src/File.php --sniffs="PSR12.Functions.NullableTypeDeclaration"
```

Get the sniff names from

```
./vendor/bin/phpcs -e
```

e.g.

```
Generic (15 sniffs)
-------------------
  Generic.ControlStructures.InlineControlStructure
  Generic.Files.ByteOrderMark
  Generic.Files.LineEndings
  Generic.Files.LineLength
  Generic.Formatting.DisallowMultipleStatements
  Generic.Functions.FunctionCallArgumentSpacing
  Generic.NamingConventions.UpperCaseConstantName
  Generic.PHP.DisallowAlternativePHPTags
  Generic.PHP.DisallowShortOpenTag
  Generic.PHP.LowerCaseConstant
  Generic.PHP.LowerCaseKeyword
  Generic.PHP.LowerCaseType
  Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowTabIndent
  Generic.WhiteSpace.IncrementDecrementSpacing
  Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent

PEAR (1 sniff)
---------------
  PEAR.Functions.ValidDefaultValue

PSR1 (3 sniffs)
---------------
  PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration
  PSR1.Files.SideEffects
  PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName

PSR2 (9 sniffs)
---------------
  PSR2.Classes.ClassDeclaration
  PSR2.Classes.PropertyDeclaration
  PSR2.ControlStructures.ElseIfDeclaration
  PSR2.ControlStructures.SwitchDeclaration
  PSR2.Files.ClosingTag
  PSR2.Files.EndFileNewline
  PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature
  PSR2.Methods.FunctionClosingBrace
  PSR2.Methods.MethodDeclaration

Squiz (15 sniffs)
-----------------
  Squiz.Classes.ValidClassName
  Squiz.ControlStructures.ControlSignature
  Squiz.ControlStructures.ForEachLoopDeclaration
  Squiz.ControlStructures.ForLoopDeclaration
  Squiz.ControlStructures.LowercaseDeclaration
  Squiz.Functions.FunctionDeclaration
  Squiz.Functions.FunctionDeclarationArgumentSpacing
  Squiz.Functions.LowercaseFunctionKeywords
  Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration
  Squiz.Scope.MethodScope
  Squiz.WhiteSpace.CastSpacing
  Squiz.WhiteSpace.ControlStructureSpacing
  Squiz.WhiteSpace.ScopeClosingBrace
  Squiz.WhiteSpace.ScopeKeywordSpacing
  Squiz.WhiteSpace.SuperfluousWhitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run phbcbf on a specific error message within a specific sniff file by using the exclude rules like you have listed in the sample code above. You can use the xml file directly in the phbcbf command

```
phpcbf --standard=path_to_your_ruleset_file.xml
```

Trying to run phpcbf by selecting specific sniffs in the command line did not allow me to do this though.

This was the only rule that I had in the custom ruleset file

```
<rule ref="Drupal.Commenting.FunctionComment">
  <exclude name="Drupal.Commenting.FunctionComment.Missing"/>
  <exclude name="Drupal.Commenting.FunctionComment.MissingFile"/>
  <exclude name="Drupal.Commenting.FunctionComment.MissingParamType"/>
  <exclude name="Drupal.Commenting.FunctionComment.WrongStyle"/>
  <exclude name="Drupal.Commenting.FunctionComment.ParamCommentNewLine"/>
  <exclude name="Drupal.Commenting.FunctionComment.IncorrectParamVarName"/>
  <exclude name="Drupal.Commenting.FunctionComment.SpacingAfter"/>
  <exclude name="Drupal.Commenting.FunctionComment.SpacingAfterParamType"/>
</rule>
```

Do note that I did not explicitly exclude all the possible errors but instead only excluded the errors that were present in the codebase I was running this for. The only error I wanted to fix was the one I did not include in the exclude list.